# SQL Server query sorting on multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I am ordering by two columns in my query one is the sales representative's name and the other is the status of their tasks. for instance. The status columns should be sorted (Pending, Sent, Out for Signature). I am going to make a report based on this query. Status report sort isn't in ascending or descending order. Is there any way to custom sort this column?

[image]

Comment: If you have a SQL query, and it's possible to post it without including sensitive information, please include it in your post so we can see what you've tried to do so far.

Comment: Please provide what you have tried (query wise) but order by and partition by should give you a start

Comment: I've tried the case statement and was able to get the desired result. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```sql
SELECT SalesRepName, [Status]
FROM #YourTable
ORDER BY SalesRepName
    , CASE [Status]
        WHEN 'Pending'           THEN 1
        WHEN 'Sent'              THEN 2
        WHEN 'Out for signature' THEN 3
        ELSE 4
      END
```

Explanation:

You want to order by a string column, but you don't want to order alphabetically.

One way you could do this is to assign a number value to each of the possible strings you want to sort by.

One caveat to this is that if those Status labels were to ever change, then your `CASE` could suddenly stop working as you originally intended. If it is possible to reference some sort of StatusID instead, that would be better.

Or, if your business has a common workflow where one item always occurs after another. You could consider adding a "ParentStatusID" or "OrderID" of some kind to the table where you store your Statuses. This way the sorting is inherited into your query and future statuses will automatically show up in the right order on your report.